# VB.net Connecting to dataset in a different project in the same solution

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, xsd

I'm trying to connect to a dataset in a different project but in the same Solution and i'm getting the following error [(see screenshot)](http://www.screenup.info/uploads/2165660.jpeg)

I've done this before but can't for the life of me work out how I set the Datalayer project to 'public'

Any tips or hints really will be appreciated.

Thanks

Tom

Comment: Do you have a reference to the DataLayer project?

Comment: Does the not doing the import create the reference?

Comment: Sorry yes! I didn't do that, thank you! Fixed

Comment: No worries!  I will add this as answer so you can close off the question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to add the DataLayer project as a project reference.

[How to: Add or Remove References in Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky.aspx)